# How can I scrape multiple pages using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape multiple pages from a website? This code is only working for the first one:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import datetime

filename = "azet_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")+".csv"
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Descriere","Pret","Data"])
    
    r = requests.get("https://azetshop.ro/12-extensa?page=1")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    x = soup.find_all("div", "thumbnail")

    for thumbnail in x:
        descriere = thumbnail.find("h3").text.strip()
        pret = thumbnail.find("price").text.strip()
       
        writer.writerow([descriere, pret, datetime.datetime.now()])
```

Comment: kind of hard to answer without knowing the website layout. Maybe there is a difference between the first image and the rest? Have you checked how many items are in your "x" variable? perhaps soup.find_all(...) only finds one?

Comment: hello cris.sp have you test your code ? the output fill is empty ?

Answer (score 2):

For multiple pages scraping using `BeautifulSoup`, many usually do it using `while`:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import datetime

end_page_num = 50

filename = "azet_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")+".csv"
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Descriere","Pret","Data"])
    i = 1
    while i <= end_page_num:
        
        r = requests.get("https://azetshop.ro/12-extensa?page={}".format(i))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
        x = soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'thumbnail-container'})

        for thumbnail in x:
            descriere = thumbnail.find('h1', {"class": "h3 product-title"}).text.strip()
            pret = thumbnail.find('span', {"class": "price"}).text.strip()
            writer.writerow([descriere, pret, datetime.datetime.now()])
        i += 1
```

Here `i` will change with increment of `1` as scraping of a page is completed.
This will continue scraping till `end_page_num` you have defined.

Comment: hello have you test your code ? the output fill is empty ?

Comment: @AmaraBOUDIB ohh thanks, OP stated the code worked, was on that impression.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine too to use class attribute with bs4:

```
            import csv
            import requests
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            import datetime
            
            filename = "azet_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")+".csv"
            with open(filename, "w+") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(["Descriere","Pret","Data"])
            
                for i in range(1,50):
                    r = requests.get("https://azetshop.ro/12-extensa?page="+format(i))
                
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
                    array_price= soup.find_all('span', class_='price')
                    array_desc=soup.find_all('h1', class_='h3 product-title',text=True)
                    for iterator in range(0,len(array_price)):
                        descriere = array_desc[iterator].text.strip()
                        pret = array_price[iterator].text.strip()
                       
                        writer.writerow([descriere, pret, datetime.datetime.now()])
```